# React router redirect after login

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, redux-framework

I am using react router with react-redux. I need to forward to "/" (root path) after successful login from action. How can I do this in actions?

Comment: have a look at this question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268740/firing-redux-actions-in-response-to-route-transitions-in-react-router/31312139#31312139  tackles some of the issues you are going to have to deal with

Comment: @deowk I think this is actually the opposite question. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transition to another route on successful async redux action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612418/transition-to-another-route-on-successful-async-redux-action)